# Merging these arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge these 3 arrays so that the output is a 2d array holding all values from the other arrays.

Like this:

Array 1:

```
$winners = array(
    [1] => '20',
    [5] => '2'
);
```

Array 2:

```
$losers = array(
    [1] => '5',
    [2] => '1',
);
```

Array 3

```
$equal = array(
    [1] => '1',
    [2] => '2',
);
```

Result:

```
$result = array(
    [1] => array(
           [0] => '20', //First array
           [1] => '5',  //Second array
           [2] => '1'   //Third array
           ),
    [2] => array(
           [0] => '0',  //First array (Its not in the first array, so result 0)
           [1] => '1',
           [2] => '2'
           ),
    [5] => array(
           [0] => '2',
           [1] => '0',
           [2] => '0'
           ),
);
```

- I do not know what keys are in the arrays (they can be different all the time)
- Not all arrays hold exacly the same keys, it should enter 0 in the result array if not found.

Ive did some searching on the internet, but playing around with array_merge_recursive() and array_merge() did not give me the desired result. I know there are a lot of topics about merging arrays, but i just cannot find any topic doing the same thing as i do.

Comment: You should create your own function for that. We can't predict that you're going to merge stuff randomly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_merge_recursive()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) won't work for your purposes here because it will not empty fill with 0 if not present in the other arrays.

Try something like this:

```
$result = array();

// Get all distinct keys from all arrays.
// This is needed to make sure the 0 fill works.
$distinct_keys = array_unique(array_merge(
  array_keys($array1),
  array_keys($array2),
  array_keys($array3)
));

// Loop through each distinct key.
// If the index exists in each array, add it, otherwise, add '0'
foreach ($distinct_keys as $key) {
  $result[$key] = array();
  $result[$key][] = isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : '0';
  $result[$key][] = isset($array2[$key]) ? $array2[$key] : '0';
  $result[$key][] = isset($array3[$key]) ? $array3[$key] : '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but it does not add the zeros for the undefined index like in index 5, what you can do instead of wasting memory for the default value. You can write while using it:

```
if(!isset($all[5][1])) echo '0';
```

Here's the code:

```
$all = array($winners, $losers, $equals);
$output = array();
   foreach($all as $subArray){
       foreach($subArray as $key => $value){
             $output[$key][] = $value;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Something is not working about the first line. When i add it to my code it does not run.

I also do not really understand what the first line should do. Can you explain this please?

Comment: @DennyBeulen My mistake, I mixed java syntax with php syntax

Comment: Jep got it working. However, I still cannot use this. Because when there is one of the array's not in the result. I cannot see which one is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think this is the ticket!
This function will combine all arrays passed into it such that there is a key in the result for every key in the args, and the value of that key is an array with n values where n is the number of passed-in arrays. If the key for the given array exists in the corresponding passed-in array (that is, the array at the same index in the args as the index in the results sub-array), then it uses that value, else zero.

It helped me to think about the keys in the passed-in array as 'player ids', but that name could be considered arbitrary.

```
function combine_scores() {
  $result = array();
  $player_ids = array();
  $num_arrays = func_num_args();
  // get list of all 'players'
  foreach(func_get_args() as $input_array) {
    foreach($input_array as $key=>$val) {
      $player_ids[$key] = true; // memory optimization compared to $player_ids[] = $key;
    }
  }
  // setup the final array
  foreach(array_keys($player_ids) as $player_id) {
    foreach(func_get_args() as $input_array) {
      $result[$player_id][] = array_key_exists($key, $input_array) ? $input_array[$player_id] : 0;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Using it would look like this:

```
$winners = array('5'=>1);
$losers = array('2'=>3);
$result = combine_scores($winners, $losers);
```

Comment: This is indeed a nice way of doing it. Especially because it adapts itself if more arrays are passed in. What would be faster though (and why), this way, or the way Aiias does the job?

Comment: I think they will perform similarly, but this technique will scale to any number of input arrays. One performance difference will arise when there are many input arrays: the accepted technique will use more memory (temporarily) as it works to find the unique keys (because it re-creates all arrays in memory and adds them to each other before finding the unique keys). This will be trivial while the arrays are modestly sized.